# How to set text color inside a fragment fuction?

Tags: java, android

I am working with fragments. I have a `private void` type of function and inside there, I would like to set my text colors.

I have this piece of code that shows no errors.

```
verification_status.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
```

But in the view, I can't see anything, I hope someone could point me out what the right syntax would be.

Comment: Can you please provide your code for onCreateView?

Comment: I have now resolved the issue sir! It's by putting getActivity().getBaseContext(). , not only getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

Adding .`getBaseContext()` solves the problem so the proper syntax would be

```
verification_status.setTextColor(getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
```